# How can I solve alert reference errors in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I got this error

> "type error alert is not a function ".

So I created an alert function but got this error

> reference error alert is not defined

when I try to execute its function

```
function alertMessage(messageObject) {
  alert(messageObject);
  return true;
}

app.post("/login", function(req, res) {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password

  User.findOne({
      email: username
    },
    function(err, foundUser) {
      if (foundUser) {
        if (foundUser.password !== password) {
          alertMessage("Password Is Incorrect");
        } else {
          if (foundUser) {
            if (foundUser.password === password) {
              res.render("compose");
            }
          }
        };
      };

    });
});
```

Comment: Is this Server side NodeJS code? If yes, there is no `alert` function. `alert` is a function provided by browsers. If you want to log something, use `console.log()` or similar.

Comment: Your code appears to be an `express` javascript framework application hosted on `node.js`. Due to the fact that `node.js` is **not** hosted on a browser, `alert` will be undefined (hence not a function), because **node applications have no browser instances**. You should return an object to the client (`res`) and alert on the client instead.

Answer (score 1):

From `app.post`, I'm guessing this is code running in Node.js via Express.js. Node.js doesn't have an `alert` function, that's something *browsers* provide. In `app.post` you're replying to a response from the browser. If there's a login error, you need to send a reply to the post saying there's a login error. It looks like your code is expecting to present a page in response to the post (rather than being called via ajax), so you'd `render` a page saying the login failed. (You might consider using ajax instead, so the page doesn't have to refresh in this case, but that's beside the point.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I know what to do now